# Is there a way to "diff" two XMLs element-wise?

Tags: xml, comparison, diff, dtd

I'm needing to check the differences between two XMLs but not "blindly", Given that both use the same DTD, I'm actually interested in verifying wether they have the same amount of elements or if there's differences.

Comment: See this question [seaching-for-a-good-xml-diff-tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603/seaching-for-a-good-xml-diff-tool#62641)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [xmldiff](http://www.logilab.org/859) from Logilab
- [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/)
- A commercial one include in [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xml_differencing.html)

Answer (score 0):

[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_diff_and_merge.html) has good XML diff (and merge) support.

Comment: Thanks! Although it seems that it's a commercial product now.